# Setting mouse accel to specific value when pointer id changes each startup

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line

I have a set of commands that I manually enter each time I start up my Ubuntu installation (12.04). They help even out my mouse pointer acceleration as setting them in the mouse settings tab does not work (it doesn't go to the level I need).

So I do this:

```
xinput --list
```

From here, I can see the 'id' that is attached to my mouse (along with a bunch of other peripherals).

```
    Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ bcm5974                                   id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Razer Razer Naga Epic                     id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Apple Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Built-in iSight                           id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Razer Razer Naga Epic                     id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech G510 Gaming Keyboard             id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech G510 Gaming Keyboard             id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

After doing this I type the command:

```
xinput --set-prop "12" "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 3
```

I'm trying to come up with a way to automate this process on each boot, but I can't figure out how to get the id. It changes on each boot most of the time. I know that I can put the information for start up commands in `/etc/rc.local`, but I don't know how to get the dynamic id.

I hit a wall at this point:

```
xinput --list --short 'pointer:Razer Razer Naga Epic'
```

From here I can see the specific id of 12, but I can't figure out what the 'get property' command is.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find adding appropriate section to *xorg.conf* more convenient.

For example:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier      "generic mouse"
    MatchIsPointer  "yes"
    MatchProduct    "Razer Razer Naga Epic"
    Option          "SendCoreEvents"         "on"
    Option          "Emulate3Buttons"        "on"
    Option          "AccelerationScheme"     "predictable"
    Option          "ConstantDeceleration"   "3.0"
EndSection
```